# Aurelia factory resolver using parameter decoration (not class decoration)

Tags: typescript, aurelia

I know how to use the aurelia factory resolver using the `@inject` class decorator:

```
@inject(Factory.of(Foo))
export class NeedsFoo {
  foo: Foo;
  constructor(fooFactory: () => Foo) {
    this.foo = fooFactory(config);
  }
}
```

`config` is some configuration state required to initialise the Foo instance, which can't be injected.

But in some larger view models, `@autoinject` is much nicer and easier to add/remove dependencies, but I can't figure out how to use parameter decorators to achieve the same thing.

The resolvers are briefly documented [here](http://aurelia.io/docs/fundamentals/dependency-injection#resolvers) with no example of the factory resolver property. A related bug is [here](https://github.com/aurelia/dependency-injection/issues/120) but I can't figure out the usage from that. There's a bunch of SO questions but they all refer to `@inject(Factory.of(...))`

If I try the following, then fooFactory is an empty object `{}`:

```
@autoinject()
export class NeedsFoo {
  foo: Foo;
  constructor(@factory(Foo) fooFactory) {
    this.foo = fooFactory(config);
  }
}
```

A comment on the bug discussion says to do this:

```
interface FooFactory {
  new (config: any): Foo;
}

class NeedsFoo {
  foo: Foo;
  constructor(@factory(Foo) fooFactory: FooFactory) {
    this.foo = new fooFactory(config); // error!
  }
}
```

but the marked line fails with `TypeError: fooFactory is not a constructor.` (it's an empty object)

*Can I use parameter decorators and autoinject to inject a factory of a class with Aurelia?*

---

edit: renamed *deps* to *config* so it doesn't look like I'm passing injected dependencies around.

edit 2: fooFactory is an empty object, not undefined

Answer (score 3):

You're very close. Simply add `@autoinject()` to NeedsFoo in your second example, get rid of the `deps` argument and don't forget to put `@autoinject()` on Foo as well if it has deps of its own.

To further clarify how/why this works and take away a few misconceptions:

- Putting **any** decorator on a class will make tsc emit type metadata for that class. You would only use autoinject if there are simply no other decorators on the class. Is something already `@customElement()`? No need for `@autoinject()`.
- You **never** need to pass dependencies into the factory function. They're retrieved by the container inside the factory function.
- The factory function is not a class constructor, it's a constructor function. Calling it either as `fooFactory()` or `new fooFactory()` has the same effect: it invokes the function and returns whatever the function returns.
- Interfaces don't compile to javascript. Using an interface as an argument type will never make DI work. `: FooFactory` here is the same as saying `: any`. This is just for intellisense.
- When using `@factory()`, the type you pass to the function will take the place of the type of the argument itself. The type of the argument is ignored.

That gives you several alternative implementations.

Given the following class Foo

```
@autoinject()
export class Foo {
    public bar: Bar;
    constructor(bar: Bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}
```

And any of these classes NeedsFoo:

```
@autoinject()
export class NeedsFoo {
    public foo: Foo;
    constructor(@factory(Foo) fooFactory: any) {
        this.foo = new fooFactory();
    }
}

@customElement("needs-foo")
export class NeedsFoo {
    public foo: Foo;
    constructor(@factory(Foo) fooFactory: FooFactory) {
        this.foo = new fooFactory();
    }
}

@autoinject()
export class NeedsFoo {
    public foo: Foo;
    constructor(@factory(Foo) fooFactory: any) {
        this.foo = fooFactory();
    }
}

@autoinject()
export class NeedsFoo {
    public foo: Foo;
    constructor(@factory(Foo) fooFactory: FooFactory ) {
        this.foo = new fooFactory();
    }
}
interface FooFactory {
    new(): Foo;
}
```

They (as well as their different combinations) all work identical and give you an instance of `Foo` as you would expect.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but `@autoinject` is already on my second example code block! Right under _If I try the following, then fooFactory is undefined._ This is the error:
`ERROR [app-router] Error: Error invoking NeedsFoo. Check the inner error for details ... Inner Error: Message: this.fooFactory is not a function`

Comment: To clarify, `deps` are not service dependencies as I understand why they shouldn't be passed around (hence using a factory); it is factory initialization "data" / configuration. `deps` was a bad name!